# What is the solution for $\lim_{n→∞}n^{2n}/(2n!)=$??

Tags: analysis

I don't know why it diverges.
I already tried 
$$\lim_{n→∞}{a_{n+1}\over a_n}=\lim_{n→∞}{(1+1/n)^{2n+2}\over (2n+1)(2n+2)}=e^2/4.$$
But I don't know why $\lim_{n→∞}n^{2n}/(2n!)=∞$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! Hint: Use Stirling's formula.

Comment: You basically have the answer in front of you from what you've done. If $a_{n+1}/a_n\rightarrow \alpha$ then eventually we have $a_{n+1}>(\alpha-\epsilon)a_n$.

Comment: Remember, the ratio test for sequences says that if $\bigl \lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigl \rvert \rightarrow l$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $l<1$, then $a_n$ converges to $0$ and if $l>1$, $a_n$ diverges. In your case $\frac{e^2}{4} > 1$, so you have divergence.

Comment: But it is not series. Ratio teat is established in limit of seqence??

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the ratio test tells you all you want to know: the limit of the ratio is greater than 1, thus the sequence diverges.

Another way to do this is by using Stirling's approximation. We have 
$$
n!\le\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^ne^{-\frac{1}{12n}}\sqrt{2\pi n},
$$
thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!}&\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{2n}}{\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}e^{-\frac{1}{12n}}\sqrt{4\pi n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^2}{4}\right)^ne^{\frac{1}{12n}}(4\pi n)^{-1/2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n(2-\log{4})}e^{\left(\frac{1}{12n}-\frac{\log{4\pi n}}{2}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{2n-n\log{4}+\frac{1}{12n}-\frac{\log{4\pi n}}{2}}\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}
$$
Observe that the exponent in the last equation is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ and is positive for sufficiently large $n$, hence our final conclusion.